# Control the newly added functions using IntelliJ with TypeScript

Tags: typescript, webstorm

When working with IntelliJ with TypeScript and adding a reference to a new function in an .html, IntelliJ will offer to add this function to the corresponding `.component.ts` file.

Example

```
<div *ngIf="ifConditionIsTrue()">
```

IntelliJ will add this function to the component:

```
ifConditionIsTrue(){
}
```

But I want that new functions will be added like this:

```
public ifConditionIsTrue():boolean{
}
```

Is there a way to control the way new functions are added to the .ts files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find configuration for the code generated with a fix in the IDE Preferences | Editor | Code Style | TypeScript - Code Generation. The options you need are `Use 'public' modifier` and `Prefer explicit types for function declaration returns`.